# How to configure Android Virtual Device (AVD) to emulate Samsung Galaxy S3

Tags: android, sdk, android-virtual-device, samsung-mobile

I'm trying to configure Android Emulator for Samsung Galaxy S3, can anyone help me with the configuration parameters of Android Virtual Device (AVD)?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please check -

1. Target: Google APIs - API Level 15 Skin: Built-in WXGA720
2. Abstracted LCD density: 320
3. Device ram size: 512 (in emulator)
4. Hardware Back/Home: yes
5. Max VM application heap size: 48
6. Keyboard lid support: no

Comment: Hi Kanak, thanks for your answer! The Skin WXGA720 isn't in my list, i'm using the latest version of Android SDK and i'm configuring the AVD with Eclipse option "Android Virtual Device Manager". I appreciate your help.